# Datatables with latinized filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

i am trying to connect [datatables column filtering](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html) with [latinize library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/latinize)

i modified example from the first mentioned site to this so far

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#allRepsTable thead tr').clone(true).appendTo( '#allRepsTable thead' );
        $('#allRepsTable thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function (i) {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;">' );
     
            $( 'input', this ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                latinized = latinize(this.value)
                if ( allRepsTable.column(i).search() !== latinized ) {
                    allRepsTable
                        .column(i)
                        .search( latinized )
                        .draw();
                }
            } );
        } );
```

however i only latinize the user input, not the stored data. for desired outcome, i need to latinize both.

i've been goin thru their api for some time now and i can't figure what is the best way to modify their data for search purpose only, with the original data being shown.

Comment: My suggestion is to add a hidden, but searchable, extra column to your data table. You can follows the approach shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63582795/12567365), which handles both the table data and the search terms. That example uses a different "latinization" library, and it uses the global search box, not a column filter. But apart from that, I think it should give you some ideas.

Comment: Alternative suggestion: If you have a separate search input for each column, then the above approach may be unwieldy (many extra hidden columns needed). In that case, use [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data) - either with a column render function or with HTML 5 attributes. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66564542/datatable-is-considering-custom-attribute-data-while-search/66588669#66588669) for an example of this for a column render function.

Comment: thank you very much! this is exactly what i was looking for. to be concrete, the html5 part with `<td data-search="Tiger Nixon">T. Nixon</td>`. you can post this as an answer co i can mark it as solved. if you dont want to, i will post it later. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to [andrewjames](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12567365/andrewjames) i solved my problem accordingly:

[orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data) offers html 5 `data-search`

so my `<td>`s were transformed from

```
<td>{{ $rep->user->full_name }}</td>
```

to

```
<td data-search="{{ Str::ascii($rep->user->full_name) }}">{{ $rep->user->full_name }}</td>
```

using [laravel's helper](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-ascii), but other libraries that normalize/latinize/transform text to ascii should work too.

then [latinize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/latinize) did the same trick for the javascript part

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#allRepsTable thead tr').clone(true).appendTo( '#allRepsTable thead' );
        $('#allRepsTable thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function (i) {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;">' );
     
            $( 'input', this ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                latinized = latinize(this.value)
                if ( allRepsTable.column(i).search() !== latinized ) {
                    allRepsTable
                        .column(i)
                        .search( latinized )
                        .draw();
                }
            } );
        } );
});
```